# Dual operator on continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

> Show that the following operators belong to the dual of $C([a, b])$, $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ [...]

It's the beginning of a question I just read. I was wondering what exactly the dual of $C([a,b])$ is and how to check if an operator is in the dual of a space.

I know that the dual space of $X$ is the space of all linear maps from $X\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$. So in this case all linear maps from $C([a,b]) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, linear maps from $C([a,b])$ to $\mathbb{R}$, though depending on context "dual" may refer to only those maps which are *continuous*.  It's a standard fact that such a linear map (aka functional) $\ell$ is continuous iff there exists a constant $C_\ell$ such that $|\ell(f)| \le C_\ell \|f\|$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the sup norm.

Comment: @NateEldredge So if I understand correctly, what I really need to show is boundedness of the operator because then it's a continuous linear map?

Comment: Yes, especially if this is from a functional analysis book or course - "continuous / bounded" is usually implicit in such a context.  Linearity is usually trivial.

Comment: That's true. It's a func. analysis course, we've already discussed the continuous/boundedness equivalence and our operators are linear by default. Thanks for your help!